# Data manipulation with div classes and forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to take content from a div class one by one and then load it into array? Then I need to insert these one by one to some other div class.
Basically, I have 2 forms, one of which is dummy and this dummy gets its content from CMS. The dummy form is hidden, while real form is shown, but empty at first.
I need to use jquery to take dummy text from form and insert it to real form.

Something like this:

```
  <form name="real" method="post" action=""> 
  <input type="text" name="first" id="a"/> 
  <input type="text" name="second" id="b"/> 
  <input type="text" name="third" id="c"/> 
  <input type="text" name="fourth" id="d"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
  </form> 

  <form name="extract" style="display:none;"> 
  <div class="generic">data_1</div> 
  <div class="generic">data_2</div> 
  <div class="generic">data_3</div> 
  <div class="generic">data_4</div> 
  </form>
```

must become something like this:

```
  <form name="real" method="post" action=""> 
  data_1 <input type="text" name="first" id="a"/> 
  data_2 <input type="text" name="second" id="b"/> 
  data_3 <input type="text" name="third" id="c"/> 
  data_4 <input type="text" name="fourth" id="d"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
  </form>
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. For example:

```
$('[name=extract] div').each(function(index){
    $('[name=real] input:eq('+index+')').before($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seeSv/

---

edit: here are the api pages to the methods used:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/each/
http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: wow, thanks for that, does what it's supposed to do.Although it looks somewhat confusing to me. Could you give me pointers where such methods are shown and discussed? I searched jquery api for hours but nothing like this came up :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the jQuery [DataLink Plugin](http://expansive-derivation.ossreleasefeed.com/2010/10/its-the-datalink-that-binds-us-jquery-datalink/)

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer this version:

```
$('.generic').each(
    function(i){
        $('input:text').eq(i).val($(this).text());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ysfxU/).

#### Assumptions:

1. a 1:1 ratio between `div.generic`:`input[type=text]`

#### References:

1. [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/),
2. [`:text` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)
3. [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).